# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeHead' of undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new Nodejs socket.io programming. I was trying to connect socket using Flutter Socket client. But When I start to run node server (below code). It prints Server running on port 3000. But
I got error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeHead' of undefined.
It also showing at the end.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

server = app.listen(3000);

//io server
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
//3000 or any other port.
const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);

var userConnection = [];

io.on('connection', (socket)=> 
{
try
{
    console.log(`nside connection`);
    
var other_users = userConnection.filter(p=> p.meeting_id == data.meetingid);    
// data saves to userConnection variable
// connection id and socket id are same
userConnection.push({
    connectionId: socket.id,
    user_id: data.current_user_name,
    meeting_id: data.meetingid,
})

}catch(e)
{
    console.log(e);


}

})
```

error I get..

```
(node:11024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeHead' of undefined
at sendErrorMessage (D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:568:7)
at Server.handshake (D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:291:7)
at Server.onWebSocket (D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:460:12)
at D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:401:14
at WebSocketServer.completeUpgrade (D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket-server.js:330:5)    at WebSocketServer.handleUpgrade (D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket-server.js:246:10) 
at D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:400:15
at Server.verify (D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:172:43)
at Server.handleUpgrade (D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:384:10)
at Server.<anonymous> (D:\1ask\9105task\server145\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:511:16)
```

(node:11024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11024) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Is the error coming when trying to just run the above code or are you trying to load a url/route? Because writeHead usually indicates it was trying write a response.

Comment: i am just trying to run the above code

Comment: it shows server running on port number

Comment: after that error comes

Comment: I updated the question and error console also shown

Comment: Maybe rewrite the code with http createServer as per socketIO example: https://socket.io/get-started/chat#Integrating-Socket-IO

Comment: Yes, that works. What's the difference between this code and mine.

Comment: socket io needs http server for initialization(https://stackoverflow.com/a/33188380/5773530). Your error seems to be coming from that step so I suggested to go with http createServer. But express creates http server server too so it should work, and I tried your code locally without any issue. So it could be a specific version issue, but I don't really know :)